# Remove textarea inner shadow on Mobile Safari (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, mobile, mobile-safari

By default, it seems Mobile Safari adds the top inner shadow to all input fields, including textarea. Is there a way to remove it?

It's especially ugly when you have a white background.

Answer (score 359, accepted):

By adding this css style:

```
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
```

As per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance

Comment: be careful when adding this property on input type checkbox and radio button selectors, because it hides the checkboxes and radio buttons ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Lyon. Btw, the best way to use it is to apply it only to `textarea, input[type="text"], input[type="submit"]`.

Comment: Also don't apply this property to `select` element since it will look like normal input text.

Comment: Don't forget `input[type="password"]` too.

Comment: Don't forget `[type="email"]` too!

Comment: Might be easier to use the not operator depending on what input types you are using: `input:not([type=checkbox]):not([type=radio])`

Comment: Also be careful not to apply this to <select>, because this will remove the drop-down arrow at the end of the field.

Answer (score 32):

While adding the CSS style

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

will work, it gets rid of everything.  You may want to try this instead:

```
box-shadow: none !important;
```

This way you keep the down-arrow.

Comment: Just adding box-shadow property does not work. Inner shadow still shows up in Safari on iOS.

Answer (score 32):

Here is the easy solution

```
input[type=text] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Sometimes you can have a stylesheet there broke the `appearance: none;` so a way to fix it when that happens is to use `caret`. The best way will be to rewrite your code and find out what's part of your code there mess up the style for `none`

Before using `caret` you need to know that it can get you some trouble with other styles

```
-webkit-appearance: caret;
   -moz-appearance: caret;
     -o-appearance: caret;
        appearance: caret;
```

> **NOTE:** Use `none`, `caret` is not the optimal.

Answer (score 4):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51626446/9287284

> `background-clip: padding-box;`

and I found an older same answers comment at here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29750016/9287284

Answer (score -31):

Setting either `background` and `border` css properties of the `input` tag also seems to work.

Try this:

```
<style>
input {
    background: #ccc;
    border: none;
}
</style>

<form>
First name: <input type="text"/><br />
Last name: <input type="text" />
</form>
```

Comment: Incorrect and misleading. Please test your code on the right device before posting...

Comment: Really wrong answer, nothing about it is what OP ask about