# remove inner shadow of text input

Tags: html, css, input

So I have a text input, im using html5, on chrome, and I want to change the look of a text input, I've removed the outline on focus (orange on chrome), I set the background to a light color `#f1f1f1` but now there is like a thicker border on the top and left sides, like it's meant to look pushed in, when there is no change in background color this doesn't happen. How do I remove it? Sorry I can't provide a picture, on a mobile device.

It happens on chrome, ie, and Firefox, can't test any others.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

`border-style:solid;` will override the `inset` style. Which is what you asked.

`border:none` will remove the border all together.

`border-width:1px` will set it up to be kind of like before the background change.

`border:1px solid #cccccc` is more specific and applies all three, width, style and color.

Example: https://jsbin.com/quleh/2/edit?html,output

Comment: The first line, `border-style: solid`, is the best answer to this question.

Comment: border-style: none was the answer is was looking for

Answer (score 53):

This is the solution for mobile safari:

```
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
```

as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance

and as suggested here: [Remove textarea inner shadow on Mobile Safari (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062968/remove-textarea-inner-shadow-on-mobile-safari-iphone)

Comment: Works as a charm

Answer (score 30):

None of the solution are working currently.
Here is my solution. You can add prefixes.

```
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 0px red;
```

Answer (score 19):

Add `border: none` or `border: 0` to remove border at all, or `border: 1px solid #ccc` to make border thin and flat.

To remove ghost padding in Firefox, you can use `::-moz-focus-inner`:

```
::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

See [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZdQnX/).

Comment: When I do this it has no border, yeah, but when I set the border to 1px and set the color to black only two sides are set. The other is white.

Answer (score 12):

Set `border: 1px solid black` to make all sides equals and remove any kind of custom border (other than solid).
Also, set `box-shadow: none` to remove any inset shadow applied to it.

Comment: If I set the border to any other color, lets say #eee, only two sides are still being set

Comment: Look my update. You may need to change border style and size too, to `solid` and `1px`.

Comment: Thanks. I based mine of yours so yeah.

Comment: box-shadow was what made the solution work for me, no other solutions had this bit.

Answer (score 9):

Try this 
`outline: none;`

live demo https://codepen.io/wenpingguo/pen/KQgbXq

Answer (score 3):

All browsers, including Safari (+ mobile):

```
input[type=text] {   
    /* Remove */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    
    /* Optional */
    border: solid;
    box-shadow: none;
    /*etc.*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on firefox. and I was having the same issue, input type text are auto defined something looks like boxshadow inset, but it's not. 
the you want to change is border... just setting `border:0;` and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

here is a small snippet that might be cool to try out:

```
input {
border-radius: 10px;
border-color: violet;
border-style: solid;
}
```

note that: `border-style` removes the inner shadow.

```css
input {
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-color: violet;
    border-style: solid;
  }
```

```html
<input type="text"/>
```