# Remove default input inner shadow in Firefox on Android

Tags: android, css, firefox

There is a default inner shadow on the input element in Firefox on Android.

Is it possible to remove it with CSS?

Comment: Check out [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791631/remove-inner-shadow-of-text-input).

Comment: I've seen it, it does not work.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, the solution is:

```
background-image: none;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
::-moz-focus-inner {border: 0;padding: 0;}
```