# How to remove innser shadow in Text field

Tags: javafx

I want to remove the inner shadow in TextField.

[image]

Here is css.

```
-fx-font-size: 12px;
-fx-font-family: "Segoe UI Semibold";
-fx-pref-width:250px;
-fx-pref-height:35px;
-fx-background-radius:0px;
```

Comment: Have you tried other solutions? The questions might be a duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791631/remove-inner-shadow-of-text-input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this line:

`-fx-background-color: -fx-text-box-border, -fx-control-inner-background;`

Comment: From where you learn these tricks? I really want to be professional in Java, JavaFX, Java EE. now working in JavaFX.. can you give me reference from where I can be professional in JavaFX? mean want to learn everything related to JavaFX can you give me reference Please?

Comment: @UnKnown I just compiled [cssGuide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html), [caspian](https://gist.github.com/bionicrm/c90c03c645d18722ddb0), [modena](https://gist.github.com/maxd/63691840fc372f22f470).

Comment: amazing links..!! Are these links would be enough to be professional in JavaFX CSS? if you have more links ( which describes details too ) please give me.

Comment: @UnKnown + [pseudoClass](http://harmoniccode.blogspot.ru/2013/05/css-confusing-style-sheets.html), [cssUtilities](http://www.guigarage.com/2014/03/javafx-css-utilities/) and much more in google :)

Comment: Really I'm learning day and night. But I stuck when I have nothing to read or unable to find the exact source. You are great. These will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it is NOT shadow. It is a specially decorated background. So making it transparent or putting a key which its value is transparent will work well.

```
.text-field {
    -fx-text-box-border: transparent;
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
 }

 .text-field:focused {
     -fx-faint-focus-color: transparent; /*JavaFX 8*/
     -fx-focus-color: transparent; /*JavaFX 2.2*/
 }
```

The style code above(style.css) will generate a text field without any border and background and make it clear. By the way putting -fx-border-color or -fx-faint-color instead of transparent in -fx-background-color is completely fine since their value is transparent.

Edit: I'm adding now a little example code.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class TextFieldDemo extends Application {

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setPromptText("TextField");
        textField.setMaxWidth(100);
        textField.setLayoutX(50);
        textField.setLayoutY(25);
        textField.setFocusTraversable(false);
        Rectangle background = new Rectangle(40, 20, 120, 40);
        background.setStyle("-fx-arc-width: 40px; -fx-arc-height: 40px;-fx-fill: yellow;");
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Pane(background, textField), 200, 80);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("style.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Example Output:
[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVt0Z.png)