# -webkit-appearance: caret; removes input border from android and windows browsers

Tags: android, html, css, webkit

i just write this line

```
input, textarea{-webkit-appearance: caret;-moz-appearance: caret;}
```

[image: remove input border screenshot]
[image: Original Designs]

Webkit-appearance just remove the inner shadows from ios input but it also removes the input borders from the windows and android webkit browsers.

Comment: I think to remove the inner shadow, you can try setting your own border (which will override the default) or maybe there is another way than using `appearance:caret`

Comment: In input and textarea boxes, there is my own css border. not the default one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: [Remove iOs input shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211656/remove-ios-input-shadow)

You should try removing the browser-specific styling with `appearance: none;`

```
/* Remove First */
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
/* Then Style */
```

...using your own bespoke styling.