# Disable input shadow CSS / HTML

Tags: html, css, input

When I click inside of an input box, I see the following "shadow":

[image: INPUT]

Can this be disabled? If so, how?

**EDIT:**

[GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnR7V.gif)

And this is my code

```
<div class="col-xs-12"><input class="form-control" id="Password" name="Password" type="text" placeholder="Password" /></div>
```

Comment: you can add "outline:none" for the input tag

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the border highlight on an input text element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457849/how-to-remove-the-border-highlight-on-an-input-text-element)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to set 'outline: none' on the input css.

The question was answered there: [How to remove the border highlight on an input text element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457849/how-to-remove-the-border-highlight-on-an-input-text-element)

Comment: If this is a duplicate, you should flag the question as a duplicate since you have enough reputation now.

Comment: Thanks, at that moment I hasn't, now I have.

Answer (score 1):

Set `border` to `none` or `0`. Then for mozilla remove ghost padding.

```
.myInput {
    border: 0;
}
.myInput::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try this CSS? It is also cross-browser compatible.

Answer (score 1):

From the styling, it looks like you're using iOS.
Check out this thread [Remove iOs input shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211656/remove-ios-input-shadow).
It's a couple years old, but it might help.

Comment: You should provide the general idea of the thread you mention in case the site/thread goes down, especially if it's old. If it does go down, this answer won't be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Will do so in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I just put

```
border:none;
```

And worked, that blue border desapeared

Comment: If you found the solution, you should consider marking a post as the answer if it helped you. (i.e. the green checkmark)

Answer (score 0):

Em maybe you can try to using `outline:none`,it will kill the the border when user click the input box