# CSS - Remove input shadow for radio buttons in Ipad

Tags: jquery, html, css, ipad

In Ipad there is a shadow for input boxes, I fixed it with the following css,

```
input {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

But this style cause issue for radio buttons. Radio buttons are not displayed properly. So I modified my css as follows,

```
input:not([type="radio"]) {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Now there is a shadow inside radio buttons in ipad. Please help me to find a solution to remove the shadow in radio buttons.

Comment: Can you share plz JSFiddle..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211656/remove-ios-input-shadow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211656/remove-ios-input-shadow)

Comment: Hi Rohit, this solution is for input type text...I want solution for input type radio.

Comment: Hi Codebrekers, this issue only exists in ipad.