# Remove textarea inner shadow on Iphone Safari

Tags: ios, css, iphone

OK, I've tried all solutions from posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062968/remove-textarea-inner-shadow-on-mobile-safari-iphone#comment27443750_3078353), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211656/remove-ios-input-shadow/29750016#29750016), still my textarea has this top inner shadow:
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRLAo.png).

The solution I hoped most would work was:

```
    textarea,
input[type='text'] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -o-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
```

Nothing. Btw, Inspector does detect -webkit-appearance: none for textarea and input: [Inspector img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JixDm.png).

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Some answers on the first SO question you linked to also include comments that `-webkit-appearance: none;` only worked in combination with `box-shadow: none !important;` _ Have you tried this ?

Comment: @inputforcolor, didn't gather from those answers that they must be used **together**, now solved my problem with this, thank you!